# Node - Loopback - could not able to differentiate between 'XHR' request type and other request type

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

From browser many api's triggered in which some where inline stylesheet - css, js , img, font file calls, and some other were API calls.

In Nodejs, i am using Loopback framework.I have written a middleware in server.js (like app.use).

Is there any way, to detect the only the API request and to exclude img, css, js file request in this middleware?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to check the request url. for example, url with
`/assets/` prefix is for images & css and so on. `/api/` prefixed urls 
are API requests.

Comment: @IsaacPhoenux,  I agree with you. However the folder structure is somewhat different here, and also, not all the API url's  starts with `/api`. So, i planned to look for this identifier somewhere in loopback context. 

Is the URL check; the only way to detect the request type ?

Comment: @lalithkumar Is your middleware like this:
```js
var middleWare = function(req, resp, next) { ... } 
```
According to loopback document
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-methods.html,
http path is in `req`.